# Handling Cookies in HttpWebRequest using asp.net #

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I want to know if this is do able , I make a `HttpWebRequest` in my asp.net site  and load a certain page and store cookies in  cookie container and also add cookies to the current browser from where i opened the site.

So that after this step when the user is navigated to that site (third party site) it shows the  necessary info by looking at the cookies saved instead of taking it to home page.

is this valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible because for security reasons you cannot set cookies for a different domain. You could be setting them for Amazon and manipulate their shopping cart. That is clearly something that must be impossible to do.

Comment: Is there any way around this how can i implement this, as is this was a desktop application i simply sent the post request with cookies and i get the html of a booking page(supposing i am buying a car). So how can this be replicated in case of asp.net and when i actually want the user to see the booking page (navigate to it).

Comment: You could proxy the booking site completely so that your user never leaves your domain. Then, those cookies would stay on your domain which you control. You have to forward them to the booking site with each request.

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more , some example link etc.

Comment: I understand you want to show the user the car booking page but under your own domain, right? And potentially change the contents of the page.

Comment: Nope no change in content, i want to show them the result from various site and when they click a car i want them to be redirect to the original site booking page.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work because you can't manipulate another site's cookies. If you find a way let me know and I'll cash in thousands of dollars with the Chrome security program. (You understand how unsafe it would be to be able to do that?)

Comment: OK, i thought so too by now as i did not find any thing close to my issue. So what choice do i have if i want to do the above?

Comment: You could leave the user on your own domain and show them the car booking content.

Comment: How can i do that? Will the buttons work? Like on booking page they see the form which they will fill press  a button after that maybe see a payment page to book the car etc.? Is this all doable?

Comment: This is doable if the site does not take steps to redirect you away. For example they might have absolute URLs in their forms or do something with JavaScript. This is really a speculative thing. It's all doable in theory because you could modify the response to remove any absolute URLs. But it gets impractical quickly. That's all the ideas I have for this problem.

Comment: You are correct i does not work , so i now take the user to the carlisting page instead of booking as that does not require cookies. Thank you for your help.